French comedy movie from 1965-1990
I have been trying to identify a 1965's-1990's French comedy movie. The time span is long because I saw the movie on TV a long time ago. Maybe it's from the 70's or 80's. I'm not sure.
The plot is about a three-time divorced businessman whose ex-wives have planned to leading him to bankruptcy. They ask a poor young girl to help them accomplish the plan but finally the girl and the businessman fall in love. He loses his money and as a collateral damage the ex-wives don't receive their monthly allowances! They didn't think about that!
The young girl is blond (or red-haired) and her name is Etienne or something like that. Oh, the man is on the building construction business.
